# Use named ranges to dynamically add rows in google spreadsheets, while maintaining conditional formatting in newly added rows

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-named-ranges

I have a table that looks like in Google Spreadsheets:

[image]

Some numbers in this table are calculated upon a range of cells (for instance, the total in the last row).

If I add a new row to this table, I naturally would like the total to consider the new row, without having to update every single formula. To achieve this, I use named ranges.

[image]

If I add a new row, I can simply open the named ranges window, change the size of range (say, from F2:F8 to F2:F9) without having to touch the formulas.

[image]

I would also like conditional formatting to behave like this but, unfortunately, it doesn't accept named ranges as parameters.

With this, the more computed columns I have, the more places I have to edit something if I add a new row:

[image]

This would be perfect but, as you can see, it is not accepted as valid:

[image]

How can I do this? How can I add new rows without having to update all my conditional formatting and formulas?

Answer (score 2):

At this time it's not possible to use named ranges to the "Apply to range" setting of Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sorry, but I don't understand how could I use to solve my issue. I can already count how many rows my named ranges are (and I could do that without using INDIRECT, just COUNT), but I have no idea on how I'd plug this into conditional formatting.

Comment: I'm sorry if this wasn't clear, but formulas are not the problem here: those can already refer to named ranges. I've updated my question with another screenshot.

Comment: @saturnix I removed the "noisy" part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use 1 row extra for your color scale:

Use  `F2:F9` ,When you want the color scale only over `F2:F8`. Since F9 is only "totals",It won't matter. Then when you add a row,Click 8:8 and add a row below/above. This also works for SUM. There's no need for named ranges.